# How to enable server-side processing in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring-boot, datatables

I am using DataTables but I want to switch to server-side processing in order to decrease loading times when working with large datasets, I am trying to follow this guide, but so far I've had no luck: https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables-sample

Here is my code:
**allRepresentatives.html/Or you can say index**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aegis</title>
    <!--    searchBuilder and DataTables extensions-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchbuilder/1.4.2/css/searchBuilder.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/searchbuilder/1.4.2/js/dataTables.searchBuilder.min.js"></script>
    <!--  bootstrap extensions  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .bg-light {
            --bs-bg-opacity: 1;
            background-color: rgb(171, 28, 164, 1) !important;
        }

        h2{
            color: gray;
        }

        p{
            margin: 0;
        }

        body{
            font-family: 'Open Sans', "Segoe UI Light";
        }

        .form-headings{
            background-color: rgb(71 70 70);
        }

        .form-actions{
            background-color: darkgray;
        }

        .form-headings div{
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: auto;
            margin-bottom: auto;
        }

        i{
            font-size: x-large;
        }

        a{
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .dropdown-btn{
            background-color: #f0f8ff00;
            border:0;
            color: #212529;
            font-weight:400;
            padding: 0.25rem 1rem;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 100%;
            display:block;
            text-align:start;
        }

        .dropdown-btn:hover{
            color: #1e2125;
            background-color: #e9ecef;
        }
        /**/


    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="m-5 ms-0 me-0 mb-4">
        ORGANISATIONS
    </h2>
    <div>
        <div>
        <!--For testing-->
            <label for="gender-select">Filter by Gender:</label>
            <select id="gender-select">
                <option value="all">All Employees</option>
                <option value="female">Female Employees</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="alphabet">
            <ul>
                <li th:each="letter : ${letterList}">
                    <a th:href="@{/entities(letter=${letter})}" th:class="${letter == selectedLetter} ? active : ''" th:text="${letter}"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
<!--        <button id="myTable_filter" class="btn btn-primary">Add Condition for search</button>-->
        <div id="entities" th:fragment="representatives">
            <table id="repsTable" class="display" data-order='[[1, "asc"]]' style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <div>
                    <tr th:each="rep : ${representatives}">
                        <td th:text="${rep.firstName}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${rep.lastName}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${rep.email}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${rep.gender}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${rep.company}"></td>
                    </tr>
                </div>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
let table;

$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#repsTable').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        paging: true,
        pageLength: 10,
        lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 100],
        searching: true,
        ordering: true,
        stateSave: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/rep/representatives',
            type: 'POST'
        },
        columns: [
            { data: 'id' },
            { data: 'firstName' },
            { data: 'lastName' },
            { data: 'email' },
            { data: 'gender' },
            { data: 'conpany' }
        ]
    });
});



</script>
</div>
<script th:src="@{/JS/script.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/JS/toggleFilters.js}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is my RepService.java class:**

```java
@Service
public class RepService {
    @Autowired
    private RepRepository repository;

    public Iterable<Representatives> getEntities() {
        Sort sort = Sort.by("firstName").ascending();
        return repository.findAll(sort);//This method finds all the records in the database
    }

    public Long count(){
        return repository.count();
    }

    public List<Representatives> findByEmailStartsWith(String email) {
        return repository.findByEmailStartsWith(email);
    }

}
```

**This is my RepController.java class:**

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rep")
public class RepController {
    protected final int pageSize = 10;
    @Autowired
    private RepService repService;

    @Autowired
    private RepRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @GetMapping("getRepresentativesStartingWith/{companyName}")
    ModelAndView getCompanyStartingWith(@PathVariable("companyName")
                                        String email, String fName) {
        return new ModelAndView("allRepresentatives :: representatives",
                "representatives",
                repService.findByEmailStartsWith(email));
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/representatives", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DataTablesOutput<Representatives> list(@Valid DataTablesInput input) {
        return repository.findAll(input);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/representatives", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public DataTablesOutput<Representatives> listPOST(@Valid @RequestBody DataTablesInput input) {
        int start = input.getStart();
        input.setLength(10); // Set the number of records to retrieve to 10
        return repository.findAll(input);
    }//I think that these are the two method I'm supposed to use to send and retrieve data to and from the database. **This is where I am stuck.**



    @PostMapping("/getEntities")
    @ResponseBody
    public DataTablesOutput<Representatives> getEntities(@Valid @RequestBody DataTablesInput input) {
        return repository.findAll(input);
    }
//The getFirstTenEntities method creates a ModelAndView, as well as an attribute for the data that is used to iterate over on the HTML page.
    public ModelAndView getFirstTenEntities(String returnPage, String attributeName) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView(returnPage);
        modelAndView.addObject(attributeName, repService.getEntities());
        return modelAndView;
    }
//This method just returns the viewModel `allRepresentatives.html`
    @GetMapping("getFirstTenRepresentatives")
    public ModelAndView getFirstTenReps(){
        return getFirstTenEntities("allRepresentatives",
                "representatives");
    }


}
```

**Finally the main class:**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class DatatablesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DatatablesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? Can you describe where you are specifically getting stuck? The code in your question doesn't actually use server-side processing. There is no `serverSide : true` in your DataTable (except for one that's commented out). To enable server-side processing, you need to use that option.

Comment: Also, you are using Search Builder (`dom: 'Q...`) - so that means your server-side code (Spring) would also need to look in the request payload for those extra Search Builder parameters (not generated with normal server-side processing, without `Q`). Without those request parameters, Spring cannot know which page of data is being requested. That sample guide you are trying to follow will not help you with that.

Comment: @andrewJames by no luck I mean, I've tried to use the configuration that's commented out which has the `serverSide: true` and it didn't change anything. But I think I'll try to get it without the searchBuilder for now, as that would help remove some complexity.

Comment: OK - sounds good. Processing Search Builder parameters in server-side mode is much more complicated than plain server-side processing. But even so, can you show that simpler code in your question and clarify where you are getting stuck?

Comment: @Ok I'll update it in a second, but when following the steps in the Git repository, it requires you to add the DataTables dependency to the `pom.xml` file. Next, in the repository interface (in my case the `RepRepository`)you have to extend the `DataTablesRepository`. And then in the controller class you have to create a method with a `value="url"` which would be the URL that the `serverSide: true` configuration uses for the value of the url key. So that's where I am stuck, trying to actually retrieve the data using the DataTable repository from the database.

Comment: I've updated the question a bit.

Comment: "_So that's where I am stuck_" - OK then you need to ask a much more specific and focused question about that step. Your problem has nothing to do with DataTables. It is all about following [these "Getting Started" instructions](https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables#getting-started), for the specific project you found on GitHub. Currently, your question does not even mention any of these details - and I think all the code you are showing us is irrelevant. (I see that the project _does_ have logic for Search Builder - very nice!).

Comment: This method is supposed so retrieve the data from a database and the `\representatives` value is supposed to be used by the DataTable configuration. `@RequestMapping(value = "/representatives", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DataTablesOutput<Representatives> getUsers(@Valid DataTablesInput input) {
        DataTablesOutput<Representatives> output = repository.findAll(input);
        return output;
    }` DataTable configuration: `'url': '/representatives'`. But I see this error in my browser console `tp://localhost:8080/rep/rep/representatives 404`